# Center HTML element in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, center

I want to load a web page into a WebView and center the view on a web element (a form) and force the user can not navigate through the website.

Is that possible? Anyone know how I can do?

Cristóbal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about disable touch event override

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

and do nothing by not writing any code. If you mean somrthing else, you could look at all the method of  [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)